# Can I move construct (or assign) to a map a different type values using conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, move-semantics

I have a simple container for data (simplified more for the purpose of this question) that I use as a value in a map.

I want to know if there is some way I can move construct a map with this container as a value type from a map using the underlying data type.

Here is such a class:

```
class D
{
public:
    D() :m_value(0.0){}
    D(double value) : m_value(std::move(value)) {}
    D(const D& from) : m_value(from.m_value) {}
    D(D&& from) : m_value(std::move(from.m_value)) {}
    D& operator= (const D& from) { m_value = from.m_value; return *this; }
    D& operator= (D&& from) { m_value = std::move(from.m_value); return *this; }
    ~D() = default;

    double m_value;
};
```

And here is an example of how I would like to convert it.

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, double> m = { { "1", 1.0 } };

    std::map<std::string, D> m_map = std::move(m);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::map<std::string,double,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,D,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
```

I would like to note that the main reason I would like to move construct such a map, is to avoid creating copies of the key values of the map. Which in this case is a string.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. The key of the map is `const`, and can't be moved from.

Comment: You could [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) each node one by one. The key in detached [`node_handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) is mutable - `key()` returns a non-const reference - and can therefore be moved from. You can then `emplace` the pieces into the destination map.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The reason I hoped it was doable despite the const key is that std::map's move assignment is able to do it. But I am not able to use that move assignment when the values are of different types.
I will accept your answer if no c++11 solution comes along. I wish a newer version of c++ was possible for me in this situation.

Comment: Map as a whole is movable because one instance can just hand a pointer to its underlying data structure to the other instance; that data structure is kept intact. But you want to tear up that data structure and scavenge it for parts. `extract` is the only way to do that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps (requires C++17):

```
std::map<Key, long> new_m;
while (!m.empty()) {
    auto node = m.extract(m.begin());
    new_m.emplace(std::move(node.key()), std::move(node.mapped()));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Eva4ncPP). I made a user-defined class the key of the map rather than `std::string`, so that I could instrument it and confirm it's indeed being moved and not copied.